# Do 64-bit CPUs consume more power than 32-bit ones?

Tags: power, cpu, computer-architecture

In [this lecture about efficient computing for deep learning](https://youtu.be/WbLQqPw_n88?t=452), the benchmarks show a 3-fold increase in power usage between 8-bit and 32-bit addition operations. Between 8-bit and 32-bit multiplication, the factor is 15. The same happens for floating-point operations, with a smaller effect.

Does this mean that 64-bit CPUs consume more power in general than 32-bit ones, or have I misunderstood the results? (It's not clear if these figures are due to larger numbers being manipulated more often in deep learning, or to the operations themselves consuming more energy.) Can we generalize and say that a CPU with a larger word size requires more power?

Comment: Yes, but much less than you might expect. They can and do handle 32 bit and smaller quantities which saves power; however addresses are 64 bit and that costs ... maybe 10-15% overall. There are probably studies in the MIPS R4000 era on this but you'd have to hunt for them yourself.

Comment: If you need to add two 32-bit numbers together, and a 32-bit addition uses 3x more power than 8-bit addition, and you need four 8-bit additions to perform one 32-bit addition, then the 32-bit operation saves power, because it does more with a single operation. And same goes when you need to multiply two 32-bit numbers together, as you need sixteen 8-bit multiplications, not including adding the sub-results together.

Comment: Hey, I'll give you an example. I had been coding on the ADSP-2105 doing 1024-pt, complex-in, complex-out FFTs at about 3 ms each. There was no direct FP on this chip, but I was doing hand-coded FP using its barrel shifter and other functional units. This was about 750 microJoules per 1024-pt FFT. On the newer Blackfin (a slower 200 MHz one), it was just barely able to achieve the same results in the same time. But it's power consumption was about 5 times as much. So it took about 3,500 microJoules per 1024-pt FFT. New, better part performed worse in terms of power.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that 64-bit CPUs consume more power in general than 32-bit ones, or have I misunderstood the results?

You're misunderstanding the results.  They're saying that 64 bit multiplication uses more power than 32 bit multiplication - which is true since it has to do more work.  However, doing a 64 bit multiply on a 32 bit CPU doesn't make that operation consume less power.  The same number of bits still have to be multiplied. Similarly, doing a 32 bit multiply on a 64 bit CPU doesn't necessarily consume more power.

> Can we generalize and say that a CPU with a larger word size requires more power?

From that result, no, that would be incorrect.  However, in general it makes more sense to design higher performance, higher power CPUs to be 64 bit than 8 bit, so (for unrelated reasons) that will usually be true.

Comment: I was wondering more specifically about addresses and pointer arithmetic. Do I understand right that a 64-bit CPU running 64-bit software uses only 64-bit pointers? In that case, it seems that there’s no way of avoiding the more expensive 64-bit operations on pointers. I understand why operating on larger numbers would obviously consume more.

Comment: @Hey Data bus width and address bus width can be different.